# JS: loop through list of divs to add event by onclick?

Tags: javascript

```
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
```

If I have a list of divs and want the font size to increase to 20px when clicking each one, I know I can do the following:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (var x = 0; x < elements.length; x++) {
  elements[x].addEventListener('click', () => {event.target.style.fontSize = "20px"}
}
```

Is there a way to iterate through the listen and add an `onclick` rather than doing it with the `addEventListener` way instead?   Also, *if* there is, is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Simply assign to the `.onclick` property instead of calling `addEventListener`?

Comment: your  div  have  no parent ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over all the elements. You can use [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) like the following way:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var x = 0; x < elements.length; x++) {
  elements[x].onclick = function(){
    this.style.fontSize = "20px";
  }
};
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

Please see [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) for differences.

Comment: straight forward ...thanks.  I'm aware of the benefit `addEventListener` has to allowing multiple events attached but besides that, is one way preferred over the other?

Comment: @RaymonOpie, Please visit  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 0):

You could define font sizes in a CSS Class and add those classes to all the divs.
On click, just update the CSS class's font size javascript. This won't need a loop.*<< Edit: CSS updation might need a loop ..! >>*

You can refer the following tutorial for this

http://www.shawnolson.net/a/503/altering_css_class_attributes_with_javascript.html

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want a loop, check for a click on the page, then look at the event's target (the thing that was clicked):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "DIV") {
    e.target.style.fontSize = "20px";
  }
})
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```